# texvc does not render latex math in Mediawiki

Tags: latex, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have the Math extension installed in my MediaWiki 1.19. After I updated Ubuntu Server from 12.04 to 14.04 something seems to have messed it up and it has stopped working. Basically I get the following error when I try to display anything between the `<math>` and `</math>` tags:

```
 Failed to parse (PNG conversion failed; check for correct installation 
 of latex and dvipng (or dvips + gs + convert))
```

I have tried the common troubleshooting that one can find online regarding this issue, and have recompiled `texvc` to check if that fixed the issue. The `texvc` executable in the `extensions/Math/math` directory seems to do its job when invoked from the command line. I have obviously checked that all the other executables (`latex`, `dvipng`, etc.) work as they should.

When I try to render math from my wiki, the corresponding `*.tex` file is created in `images/tmp` with the correct latex code in it, but nothing else happens.

The problem seems to be related to `texvc` having trouble invoking `latex` and `dvipng`.

What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. Basically, any shell command is passed by a security filter. So in practice, `texvc` is executed by Mediawiki through `bin/ulimit4.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -t $1 -v $2 -f $3
eval "$4"
```

where `$4` is the actual `texvc` command being run and `$2` is the amount of memory allowed for this process. The memory that comes by default is 102400 KB (exactly 100MB), which seems to be insufficient for this process to run. The amount of memory can be set in `LocalSettings.php` with the variable `$wgMaxShellMemory`. In my case I set it to 300MB, `$wgMaxShellMemory = 307200;`, which seems to be enough.

Why this small process of generating a png needs so much memory I do not know.

The reason why this stopped working *after* updating to Ubuntu 14.04 probably has to do with some newly shipped version of either `latex`, `dvipng`, `convert`, etc. requiring more memory than it did with the version that came with Ubuntu 12.04.